# Scraping 'span' tag not working

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I'm having trouble getting to the `span` tag and grabbing the inner text for "1-Day Total Return".

Here is the webpage:

http://www.morningstar.com/funds/XNAS/DODFX/quote.html

Here is my code

```
Sub Macro1()
'

link = "http://www.morningstar.com/funds/XNAS/DODFX/quote.html"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate link
        Do
        DoEvents
        Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Dim doc As HTMLDocument
        Set doc = ie.document
        While ie.readyState <> 4

        Wend
        On Error Resume Next

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

        range("B5").Offset(0, 0).Value = doc.getElementById("msqt_summary")(0).getElementsByClassName("gr_colm_a2b")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText

       End With
        ie.Quit
            Application.EnableEvents = True

'
End Sub
```

Comment: Iframe is in the page. That's an issue.

Comment: This is the url (containing exact same items) you should try with to get what you are after without hurdling with iframe: http://quotes.morningstar.com/fund/fundquote/f?t=DODFX&culture=en_us&platform=RET&viewId1=2313453521&viewId2=3167723247&viewId3=3474403256&test=QuoteiFrame

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you can get your data. The data is indeed within an iframe.

```
Sub Web_Data()

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim elem As Object, post As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "http://www.morningstar.com/funds/XNAS/DODFX/quote.html"
        Do While .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set elem = .document.getElementById("quote_quicktake").getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0)
        .navigate elem.src
        While .readyState < 4:  DoEvents:  Wend
        Set html = .document
    End With
    Set post = html.getElementsByClassName("gr_text_bigprice")(1).getElementsByTagName("span")(1)
    MsgBox post.innerText

    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Output:

```
-0.67
```